# Intercept https requests for a single browser window only

Tags: electron

I have two browser windows open, on one window I want to intercept the https request and replace the page content. Currently I'm doing this using using protocol.interceptBufferProtocol and it is working how I want it, but the https requests are being intercepted on the second window and it seems to be causing issues with the page loading.
Is there a way to only intercept requests on a specific window or a way to return the default behavior of the request?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to intercept only for protocols of a particular `session` (`ses.protocol`). Read up the [session docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session#session)

Comment: The same thing is happening when I use session.protocol.

Comment: I meant let's say using session `A` in window `W1` and nowhere else. This way the registered protocols of `A` will take effect _only_ on that window